# React-native the picker value not changing if it changes than all my prop's picker value changes

Tags: react-native, react-props, picker

React-native the picker value not changing if it changes than all my prop's picker value changes:
I am using this in TODO's list when I add new tasks and set priority, and when I change one of them priority it changes all tasks priority.
This is my code :

```
const [pickerValue, setPickerValue] = useState('Low');
<Picker style={styles.picker}  selectedValue = {pickerValue} onValueChange={(itemValue) => setPickerValue(itemValue)} >
    <Picker.Item label="Low" value="Low"/>
    <Picker.Item label="Medium" value="Medium"/>
    <Picker.Item label="High" value="High"/>
</Picker>
```

Comment: Have you defined different useState for different Pickers ?

Comment: Yes, but didn't work and also I used one picker tag. What do you mean ?

Comment: I checked that its value changing or not so I used useEffect in console its value not changing